# Separate file for boilerplate settings?

Tags: formatting

I have a LaTeX document that I plan to use regularly. I would like to put the following code in a separate file, so that I can use a single line like `\begin{customdoc}` to import all the settings. Is this possible?

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\newenvironment{theorem}[2][Theorem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{lemma}[2][Lemma]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{exercise}[2][Exercise]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{problem}[2][Problem]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{question}[2][Question]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
\newenvironment{corollary}[2][Corollary]{\begin{trivlist}
\item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #2.}]}{\end{trivlist}}
```

Comment: If you save the above as `eternusvia.tex`, you could use `\input{eternusvia} \begin{document} ...` in your document to load all these settings.

Comment: more idiomatic would be to save the file as `eternusvia.sty` and then you can use `\usepackage{eternusvia}` in the preamble.

Comment: why define theorem environments directly as lists rather than use one of the `\newtheorem` variants?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?